# CSS inheritance broken?

Tags: css, list, inheritance, nested

i have nested lists with links inside the li tags. On nesting level x I want to change the appearance of the links. Just some sample code:

CSS:

```
.blue a { color: blue; }
.red a { color: red; }
```

HTML:

```
    <ul>
    <li class="blue"><a href="#">blue-1</a></li>
    <li class="red"><a href="#">red-1</a></li>
    <li class="blue"><a href="#">blue-2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">blue-3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="red">
                        <a href="#">red-2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">red-3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">red-4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">blue-4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">blue-5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="red"><a href="#">red-5</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">red-6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">red-7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In that way it is working as expected. Links with text red-* are in red. But when I change the order of the CSS classes, it is not longer working:

```
.red a { color: red; }
.blue a { color: blue; }
```

Why this behavior? Shouldn't it be the same?
I have to use more colors than red and blue, so it is impossible to give a correct order in CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Css selector precedence is set according to how specific it is:

- every **tag** is counted as **1** point
- every **class** as **10** points
- event **id** as **100** points

Both selectors you got have the same precedence, so that one which is set further in code overrides previous ones.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that in your css you're telling **every** `a` tags that are child, grandchild, etc. elements of a class named `blue`. And that's getting overidden when you're telling that every `a` tags that are child, grandchild, etc. elements of a class named `red` should be red.

So instead of doing this (affecting all link tags)

```
.blue a { color: blue; }
.red a { color: red; }
```

You could do this (affects only the first child if it's a link tag):

```
.red > a,
.red > ul > li > a{ color: red; }
.blue > a,
.blue > ul > li > a { color: blue; }
```

What that second line does is it finds all elements that has a class name `red`. Then it finds all direct child `ul` elements. And under those matching elements it finds all direct child `li` elements that has direct child `a` elements. Matching these, it finally adds styles.

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Y9jFr/

Comment: That's ok for given example, but according to CSS precedence system it won't work on every example as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9jFr/1/. I've added `blue` class into one link on last list, but because of `.red > ul > li > a` it is red, not blue, because it has higher precedence than `.blue > a`